# How can I pass WP email adress through URL?

Tags: wordpress

I want to pass the WP user email through and url, with a button. Let's say I'm logged and I press the button, I'll going to be directed to a url like:

[www.mysite.com/me@gmail.com](http://www.mysite.com/me@gmail.com)

Where te email is dynamically selected.

I've tried to to it with Elementor dynamic tags, but had no luck with it.

Any ideas so I can build it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your request very well but you do not have 50 solutions for an email in a URL.

Add a variable !

```
www.mysite.com/?mail=me@gmail.com
```

For send mail with this email

```
<a href="mailto:me@gmail.com">me@gmail.com</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer! Let me try to explain it better...

Basically what I'd like to do is to pass some information from Wordpress to ThriveCart, in a link like this:

[https://www.mystore.com/product/?passthrough[customer_email]=me@gmail.com](https://www.mystore.com/product/?passthrough%5Bcustomer_email%5D=me@gmail.com)

What I'd like to, is send the email address from the logged user in Wordpress after the "[customer_email]="

Tank you!